# Showing $\sum_{i=0}^n c(n,i) = n!$ with cardinality of Symmetric Group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

I've come across an identity for Stirling Numbers of the first kind: $$\sum_{i=0}^n c(n,i) = n!$$

Where $c(n,k)$ is the number of permutations on [n] with exactly k cycles.
From a previous study in group theory, I recalled that a symmetric group $S_n$ contains $n!$ elements. So I wonder if there is any connection between these two? If so, can one come up with an combinatorial argument why they are the same?

Comment: Of course they're connected. If you partition a set into disjoint subsets, the cardinality of the set is the sum of the cardinalities of the subsets. So e.g. for $n=3$, observe $S_3$ admits the partition $$S_3=\big\{(123),(321)\big\}\sqcup\big\{(12)(3),(23)(1),(31)(2)\big\}\sqcup\big\{(1)(2)(3)\big\}$$ into subsets of sizes $2,3,1$ of permutations with exactly $1,2,3$ cycles respectively, so $3!=2+3+1$.

Comment: I see now, thank you!

Comment: One characterization for the unsigned Stirling Numbers of the First Kind (which you are talking about), is that $\left[n\atop k\right]$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the rising factorial $x^{\overline{n}}=x(x+1)\dots(x+n-1)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left[n\atop k\right]x^k$. Setting $x=1$ gives $$n!=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left[n\atop k\right]$$